# Why Android Studio Code Inspection result (Analyze->Inspect Code) is different from gradlew lint?

Tags: android-studio, lint

Why Android Studio Code Inspection result(Analyze->Inspect Code)  is different from gradlew lint?

Is it impossible makes same?

Comment: Their configurations are different probably